# MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit / Snackbar / Style file modify

Tags: wpf-style, material-design-in-xaml

Is there a way to do Horizontal / Center align for MaterialDesign:Snackbar ?

Here is my code.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="RemoteWpf.Views.App.AppBaseView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RemoteWpf.Views.App"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    xmlns:localConverter="clr-namespace:RemoteWpf.Converters"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:materialDesignConverters="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Converters;assembly=MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf"        
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

<materialDesign:Snackbar x:Name="MySnackbar" MessageQueue="{materialDesign:MessageQueue}">
```

[The style file is here from orignal site.](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Snackbar.xaml)

I tried to override the stylefile, but My  knowledge was too poor. I can't...

Here is what I want to make..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change `HorizontalContentAlignment` property value of `SnackbarMessage` style to `Center` as shown below.

```cs
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:SnackbarMessage}}" TargetType="{x:Type materialDesign:SnackbarMessage}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Please refer to [Overriding-Default-Styles](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Overriding-Default-Styles) page at MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a SnackbarMessage inside Snackbar like this and set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Center`:

```
<materialDesign:Snackbar MessageQueue="{Binding SnackbarMessageQueue}"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <materialDesign:SnackbarMessage HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></materialDesign:SnackbarMessage>
</materialDesign:Snackbar>
```